# Allow "console logon" (from keyboard) only for specific user

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, group-policy, runas

Currently when I create a Windows user without a password it can't be used with `runas.exe` showing the following error:

> Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced.

I want to achieve the same behavior for a specific user even while their password is not empty. It should be not possible to use any kind of automatic login like runas.exe or advapi32.dll but I still should be able to login manually by clicking and typing. How to do it?

Comment: Please define better the behavior of RunAs for that user.

Comment: @harrymc updated

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I want to create a user for elevating privileges by using "Run as administrator" while working under normal user but I don't like typing a strong password each time. Of course I want it always to happen in an interactive, non-automatic way. No software started under normal user should be able to use that admin account automatically even if it can guess the password. Working under admin account with UAC doesn't actually protects me because UAC is not a security boundary (said by MS). There are other usecases, it's just one of of them.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a security hole as a feature. How would you properly secure this?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, it's not a hole. I gonna work under standard user and sometimes need to do things under different permissions without entering a complicated password (because I already entered the password for my normal account). The security boundary is not to limit me as a user but to limit a software that is running. I want to prevent software to elevate by itself without me clicking "yes". Also I already found a way to prevent such accounts from being used from winlogon screen so other people can't enter without knowing my normal user password..

Comment: So how can we ensure that this technique doesn't get abused by malware?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, it already can't be abused when I set empty password because the group policy doesn't allow such user to be "run as" "automatically" by user space software without a UAC prompt so a malware will just get an error from winapi. I'm just asking for a way to apply the same policy for a user when it has a non-empty password.

Comment: So if you have to enter a password anyway, I don't see a problem. Just log on using the account with the password.